# When would you surround routerLink in square brackets?

Tags: angular

The Angular 2 [cheat sheet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html) shows examples of `routerLink` both with and without square brackets in templates:

```
<a routerLink="/path">
<a [routerLink]="[ '/path', routeParam ]">
<a [routerLink]="[ '/path', { matrixParam: 'value' } ]">
<a [routerLink]="[ '/path' ]" [queryParams]="{ page: 1 }">
<a [routerLink]="[ '/path' ]" fragment="anchor">
```

What's the difference in functionality?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When you put square brackets around `routerLink` (or any Angular binding) it will evaluate what you pass to it as a JavaScript expression. If you don't put square brackets around `routerLink` it will take what you pass it as a literal string.

So if you want to pass an array to routerLink or evaluate a variable then you would have to use square brackets. If you want to pass a string you could either do

```
<a routerLink="/path">
```

OR

```
<a [routerLink]="'/path'">
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want a more in-depth answer...

RouterLink is a Directive which uses the selector `routerLink` and has a Property called "routerLink".  Because the property and the selector have the same name, you only need to add brackets to the selector to bind to that property.

The `[routerLink]` Property accepts an array of path segments, followed by the params for each segment. You can use variables inside that array to create your link.

If your link won't change, then you don't need the brackets and can just assign your link to the selector using a string.

I found this in the docs: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Comment: This should be the correct answer, since the way that you create the link with the array consisted of the path segments has nothing to do with javascript expressions.

Answer (score 0):

for dynamic variables, and not strings

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30661014)